# iterate over the properties of an object in JSTL, not an array list or collection

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

I have a person object and was wondering if I can use JSTL to do something like this:

```
                        <c:forEach items="${user}" var="element"> 
                      <tr>
                        <td>${element.firstname}</td>
                        <td>${element.lastname}</td>
                        <td>${element.age}
                      </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
```

everything I've found so far points to collections or an array list.  user is stored as a session variable.

Is this possible?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no its not possible to iterate an user object. you can iterate only collections. because it is a single object .